# How to delete Contact in Windows 10 UWP, contact.DeleteAsync() METHOD IS MISSING

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

why `contact.DeleteAsync()` METHOD IS MISSING / with ERROR?

```
private static async Task DoContactDelete()
        {
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);
            var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
            
            foreach (var contact in contacts) {
             var Text = contact.ToString();
             // ONLY THIS ONE METHOD AVAILABLE, contact.DeleteAsync() METHOD IS MISSING

        await contact.DeleteAsync();
// Error   CS1061  'Contact' does not contain a definition for
 'DeleteAsync' and no accessible extension method 'DeleteAsync' 
//accepting a first argument of type 'Contact' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?
            }
        }
```

This line is with Error:

```
await contact.DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: [ContactList.DeleteContactAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactlist.deletecontactasync)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document for the [Contact Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact?view=winrt-22621), there is no Delete method available. The behavior you get is expected.

Comment: Hi, OK, THIS WORKS....in My LUMIA 950.. 
var contactStore = await contactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadWrite);
               var contactLists = await contactStore.FindContactListsAsync();
               foreach (var list in contactLists)
            {
                var contactReader = list.GetContactReader();
                var contacts = await contactReader.ReadBatchAsync();
                foreach (var contact in contacts.Contacts)
                { await list.DeleteContactAsync(contact); }}}

Comment: @Pacala_ba Glad to hear that. You could post it as answer and accept it. This will help others with the same problem.